# MYSQL SELECT 2 counts on same field

Tags: mysql

Imagine this db structure:

```
`id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`correct` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
```

I want to get the count of all entries with `correct = 1`, *and* the count of all entries with `correct = 0`, in *one* query.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using GROUP BY should solve the problem:

```
SELECT correct, COUNT(*) FROM table GROUP BY correct;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(case when correct = 0 then 1 end) as ZeroCount,
    count(case when correct = 1 then 1 end) as OneCount
from MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the counts in one row:

```
SELECT SUM(correct=0) as number_of_zeros,SUM(correct=1) as number_of_ones
FROM table;
```

If you want them in multiple rows:

```
SELECT correct,COUNT(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY correct;
```